# Shifting Curves: Is this the correct way of doing it?

Tags: functions

Say I am given a sketch of some function $y=f(x)$, and were to draw $y=f(2x-3)$ based on the given diagram.

Would I be correct in saying this?

1. Shift the curve to the right by 3 units, thereby turning $f(x)$ into $f(x-3)$
2. 'Squash' the curve horizontally by a factor of 2, thereby replacing $x$ with $2x$ and therefore acquiring $f(2x-3)$

Comment: Furthermore, is this equivalent?

1. Sketch y=f(2x)

2. Shift that curve to the right by 3/2 units.

Comment: It all looks good to me. (BTW, instead of adding a comment, you should edit your question. Otherwise people might miss it.)

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$2x - 3 = 2\left(x - \frac{3}{2}\right)$$

Hence, the curve is squashed horizontally by a factor of $2$, but the horizontal translation is by $3/2$ instead of $3$.

Example.  Let $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$.  Then

$$f(2x - 3) = \sqrt{2x - 3} = \sqrt{2\left(x - \frac{3}{2}\right)}$$

The domain of $f(x)$ is $D_f = [0, \infty)$, while the domain of $g(x) = f(2x - 3)$ is $$D_g = \left[\frac{3}{2}, \infty\right)$$

The graph below shows the transformations.  [image: transformations_of_square_root_graph]